# Facing AFNetworking Errors after upgrading xcode to version 10.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

Today, I upgraded my xcode version from 10.1 to version 10.2. In xcode 10.1 my project was working fine but after upgrading it to 10.2 I am facing following errors. I am using pods to integrate library in my project. The pod versions are as follows:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', 3.1.0
pod 'AFOAuth2Manager', '3.0.0'
pod 'AFNetworking+streaming', '1.0.2'
```

I checked on cocoapods and both libraries are of latest versions.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: first update your cocoapods then update your pod update file.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow

1. Remove work space
2. Remove Pod folder
3. Remove Podlock file
4. Terminal Command on root

   > sudo gem install cocoapods
5. run

   > pod install
6. Now Run workspace.

Comment: I went through the steps you mentioned but I am getting same  errors.

Comment: Did you clean project & delete derived data?

Comment: So, can you try making new project, simply demo app and add only this library and run app. it will may narrow down problem